# Instantiate prefab with a customize position and rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to Instantiate a prefab and it is so weird that the position of my instantiated prefab are slanting.

[image]
My code is simple as this

```
public Transform Knights;

void Start(){
    //instantiate 6 copies of knights 2 units far apart from each other
    for(int i = 0;  i < 6; i++){
        Instantiate (Knights , new Vector3((i * 1.0f) + transform.position.x, transform.position.y,
            transform.position.z), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,42,0)));

    }
```

I want it to be more like this.

[image]

Comment: I would try replacing the ´transform.position´ lines in your code with ´Knights.position´.  This will make sure the knights are being created from the position of the first knight.  That's just a guess, though, but perhaps the line of knights you're trying to create is not aligned with the X axis?

Comment: It is still the same . What i did here is that script from my question is attached to an empty gameobject. Then i created a prefab that has a position of x=308,y=0.39,z=99 . The problem the x axis increments (i.e 1st Prefab its x = 308 the 2nd prefab its x = 309 and the 3rd prefab is x = 310 and so on up to 6th prefab

Comment: Probably you will have to reduce or increase the z also in the vector because they are not aligned as I can see from the squares.
try putting `transform.position.z - 1.0f * i` and if you need more distance between them multiply the i by **2.0f insteed of 1.0f**

Comment: It could have something to do with the 42° rotation of the knights.  If you remove that, perhaps something is different?  Other than that, I'm not sure what it could be.  Perhaps you should edit your question to include the expected position of the knights and what the actual position comes out to be.

Comment: @S.Fragkos sir put it as an answer i'll mark it as correct . Yeah it wasn't align that was so dumb of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will have to reduce or increase the z also in the vector because they are not aligned as I can see from the squares. try putting
 `transform.position.z - 1.0f * i` 
and if you need more distance between them multiply the i by 2.0f insteed of 1.0f

Comment: Thank you very much